# How to get first array value of "name" variable

Tags: javascript

I can't get array value but coding is correct but showing my array first character onle and also not working my variable could you please solve my issues.

my code:

```js
 var name = ["siva", "mani", "sundar", "ranjith"];
 console.log(name[0]);
```

Comment: are you getting an error or odd result?

Comment: my code is javascript could you please solve my issue.

Comment: my result is "s"

Comment: `name` is a reserved property of `window` and it contains the name of the window.

Comment: Yes, I am sure if I use var name1 variable working properly. but I declared variable name as "name" not working.